# Find a path that covers as many nodes as possible

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following interesting problem. Given a graph $G$, an agent starts to mark nodes in $G$ in the following way: it marks all nodes within distance $d$ from it. Now the question is to find the itinerary for the agent such that given the time duration $t$, it can mark as many nodes as possible, assuming that it moves at a constant speed. In other words, find a path of length $l$ along which the agent can mark as many nodes as possile.

I would like to know if it reduces to some standard problem in graph theory. Is it NP-hard, if yes, is there any constant approximation algorithm that solves it?
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Thanks Dima for your comment. However, the problem of Hamiltonian path is focused on topological graphs, while the problem I posed is on geometric graphs.

Comment: If the agent arrives at a node, and an already marked node is within distance $d$, is the agent re-marking the node or not? If yes, you assign to each vertex the number of nodes within distance $n$ and the problem  reduces to finding the path of lenght $l$ with maximal vertex number sum.

Comment: @NickS Thanks Nick. No, the agent won't remark the node. By the way, in your response, how to find a path with maximal vertex number sum?

Comment: just think of all your edges having length 1 each.

Comment: if you are able to solve your problem exactly for graphs with each edge of length 1, and for $d$ sufficiently big, then you can solve Hamiltonian Path exactly. That is, your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: @user52871 not sure as this is far from my expertize area, but the problem seems one of those which can be solved by calculating high powers of the right matrix, maybe with addition/multiplication defined in a different way.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I think that "path" means "walk" in the problem, note that many books use "simple path"/"path" to denote path/walk...

Comment: right, the poster means "walk".

Comment: @NickS : calculating powers usually allows one to solve shortest paths problems; here it's more like longest path problem...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik If you replace the numbers by their negatives, the longest walk problem becomes the shortest walk problem. OR, if you prefer to work with positive numbers, just pick some $M$ which is larger than all $n_i$ and  replace $n_i$ by $M-n_i$... The problem then becomes the problem of finding the shortest walk of $l$ steps...

Comment: @NickS : mere existence of a walk of $\ell$ steps is NP-hard, disregarding the edge lengths.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Existence of a walk of $l$ steps is trivial, is is the existence of a (simple) path of length $l$ which is hard.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik For example, if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$ then $G$ has a walk of lenght $l$ if and only if $A^l \neq 0$, this is NOT NP-hard..... Or, a much simpler argument, walks allow reusage of edges, and if $e$ is an edge, one can create walks of arbitrary length by simply walking back and forth on $e$....

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems that the problem can be related to the orienteering problem which is NP-hard. However, the difference is that The orienteering problem works on topological graphs while the problem I posed on geometric graphs.